# For loop make new variables for you - VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, function, variables, loops, for-loop

I'm trying to make a for loop for will make a new variable for me, every step. I want something like this. What ever step I am on, say, x = 2, it Dims newVar2, if x = 3: Dim newVar3

Is there any way to do that? I was hoping something like, Dim newVar & x would work, but of course now.

I was trying to do it as an array, but I'm not sure how to do that, or ReDimming, so examples would be great!

Comment: You could simply use an array. Why you want something like that?

Comment: You could Dim once before the loop and ReDim within the loop. Is that what you want?

Comment: could you show me how to do this? I'm not sure how to do an array with this, or Dimming and ReDimming

Comment: If you want to add new items to a collection, (and you don't know the maximum size of the collection) you should use a `List(Of t)` object instead.

Comment: easiest way is to build to a list.

Comment: If you want to be able to quick retrieve these values "by name" then use a Dictionary() with the variable name as the key.

Answer (score 4):

To create a collection of variable values inside a for loop, you should use a `List(Of t)` object or something similar (For Example `Dictionary`).

To do this with a `List(Of t)` you can do the following :

```
Dim varList As New List(Of Integer)

For i As Integer = 0 To 10
   varList.add(i)
Next
```

Or if you want to do it with the variable names you mentioned, try :

```
Dim varList As New List(Of String)

For i As Integer = 0 To 10
   varList.add("newVar" & i)
Next
```

To retrieve the value from a List use the following : `Dim result As String = varList(0)`

Alternatively you can use a Dictionary object to store `Key/Value` pairs :

```
Dim varList As New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)

For i As Integer = 0 To 10
   Dim k As Integer = 0
   varList.add("newVar" & i, k)
Next
```

Becareful though as a Dictionary object can only contain unique Keys. To return the value find it as : `Dim result As Integer = varList("newVar0")`

Answer (score 1):

basic array:

```
 Dim Arr(1000) As Integer
 For i As Integer = 0 To 999
     Arr(i) = YYYYY
 Next
```

trick for dynamic size:

```
Dim max As Integer = XXXXXX
Dim Arr(1000) As Integer
For i As Integer = 0 To max
    'if too small, Increasing array without loss old data
    If Arr.Length = i Then
        ReDim Preserve Arr(Arr.Length + 1000)
    End If

    Arr(i) = YYYYY
Next
```

or, use list:

```
Dim max As Integer = XXXXXX
Dim list As New List(Of Integer)
For i As Integer = 0 To max
    list.Add(YYYYY)
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are technically correct, but you probably don't need the iteration loops.  You can probably do this in a single line of code:

```
Dim varList As Dictionary(Of String, String) = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).ToDictionary(Function(k) "newVar" & k, Function(v) "Some value for newVar" & v)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim myInts As New List(Of Int)

For i = 0 To 10
    myInts.Add(i)
Next
```